# Getting records from a table which have non-null values for a particular column in all months

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
Project_Id  Period  Value

123 Jan-15  0
123 Feb-15  34
123 Mar-15  78
123 Apr-15  56
456 Jan-15  0
456 Feb-15  0
456 Mar-15  0
456 Apr-15  0
789 Jan-15  45
789 Feb-15  4
789 Mar-15  18
789 Apr-15  26
```

I need to retrieve Project data only when i do not have 0 for Value field in all the months like:

```
Project_Id  Period  Value
123 Jan-15  0
123 Feb-15  34
123 Mar-15  78
123 Apr-15  56
789 Jan-15  45
789 Feb-15  4
789 Mar-15  18
789 Apr-15  26
```

Project no `456` should not come in my result because for all the months the value is `0` for that particular project.

Can someone help me with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM` and `COUNT` to determine the number of 0 `Value`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE project_id IN(
    SELECT project_id
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY project_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> COUNT(*)
)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2c27/1/0)

---

Another solution is to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tbl t2 WHERE t2.project_id = t1.project_id AND t2.Value > 0
)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2c27/2/0)

Comment: You had me doubting myself there for a second, heheh.

Answer (score 0):

The inner select gets all `project_id`s that have a least one `value` that is not `0`.

```
select * from your_table
where project_id in 
(
  select project_id
  from your_table
  group by project_id
  having sum(case when value <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some test data but idea remains the same

```
create table #test123
   (
   pid     int,
   value int
   ) 


   insert into #test123
   select 1,0
   union all
   select 1,1
   union  all
   select 2,0
   union all
   select 2,0
   union all
   select 3,2


   select * from #test123 t2 where exists (select 1 from #test123 t1 
                                                    where t1.pid=t2.pid
                                                         group by pid
                                                      having sum(value)>0
                                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, I prefer not making a join to check for repeating values:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    Project_Id,
    Period,
    Value,
    max(abs(value)) over (Partition by Period) value
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
  Project_Id,
  Period,
  Value
FROM CTE
WHERE value > 0
```

*using abs to check for negative values. If all values are positive, the abs can be omitted.